# xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: xml

I've been trying to run an application containing google maps, but I've been getting an error in my xml file: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

The following is my xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ae.ac.adu.maps"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />  

        <activity android:name=".MapsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
</xml>
```

Why do I get the error?

Answer (score 2):

You have a `</xml>` end tag, but no matching start tag.

The XML declaration (`<?xml ?>`) is a Processing Instruction, not a start tag (it also has to go at the very start of the document, you have white space before it).

Comment: By removing the '?' I get even more errors, while by adding it in the end tag, the error is the same. This is the code copied from the tutorial for google maps in eclipse, and is supposed to be an error-free tutorial.

Comment: Don't remove the `?`, remove the rogue end tag!